# Issue using Canvas dataURL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make work a button that would open a new window with the content of my canvas in it (a rendered image of the canvas).

Here's my JS code :

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("thecanvas");
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .5)";
context.fillRect(25, 25, 125, 125);
function clickme() {
window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=200, height=500");
}​
```

HTML code :

```
<input type="button" onclick="clickme()" value="OPEN"/>

<canvas id="thecanvas" height="200" width="500" style="border:1px solid black">
```

But when I click on the "OPEN" button, nothing happens...but I really don't see why. I have looked on alot of sites for tutorials. I even copied and pasted some codes, but still nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the order in which you execute your statements matters. You need to call `toDataURL` after you draw to the canvas, or the dataURL generated with not contain that content.

I'm not sure what your script tags are like, but here's a working example that does the event in a slightly more foolproof way: http://jsfiddle.net/b7G6J/

HTML:

```
<input id="thebutton" type="button" value="OPEN"/>

<canvas id="thecanvas" height="200" width="500" style="border:1px solid black">
```

JS:

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("thecanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// First drawing commands
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .5)";
context.fillRect(25, 25, 125, 125);
// Then toDataURL
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

var button = document.getElementById("thebutton");
button.onclick =function() {
  window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=200, height=500");
}
```

​

Comment: Thank you! Pretty logic that I had to call the dataURL after, so it can saves what has been put in the canvas. Thanks again!